# How to create javascript array from database by php

Tags: javascript, php

I want to create a javascript array from databse like this:

```
var m = [
[one]
[two]
[three]
]
```

it is important that typeof m be object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

```
$phparray; // This is your php array 

$jsArray = <?php echo json_encode($phparray); ?>;

//do stuff with $jsArray now
```